# How to add Color Picker in Theme Options for the following?

Tags: theme-development, plugin-recommendation, theme-options, child-theme, color-picker

I have a landscaping09 theme.

This is what I want:

A theme options page with the following options:

->Theme color background change (with colorpicker) or url of the image

->General Navbar color background change (with colorpicker) or url of the image

->Header color background change (with colorpicker) or url of the image

->Set up header height

->Navbar color background change (with colorpicker) or url of the image

->Navbar hover color background change (with colorpicker) or url of the image

->Footer color background change (with colorpicker) or url of the image

->additional css code box

please let me know how to do it or any plugin will do these things?

please help me.

Comment: WordPress includes the [farbtastic](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic) script(jQuery color picker), you could leverage that for color picking(i've used it before it's pretty straight-forward).

Comment: Just a note, if you want to know what scripts are already added to WP Admin, including Farbtastic, go here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_scripts_included_with_WordPress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not going to get an answer to this, there is no magic wand you can use to change what your asking without working it out yourself, or at the very least supplying some actual code with your question.

To change the CSS in a back-end option page you can use the Options API, http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API, or write a custom CSS file and include it in your header.

As Mark already mentioned there is a color picker that comes with WordPress that you can use to fill in your custom field options with color values.

Comment: Yes, yes it does.

Comment: does it really comes with WordPress ? ready to use ? how do I use it ? can you name it ?

Comment: `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );`